# SSH permission denial

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

Not sure why all of a sudden I'm getting a permission denied when pushing to Heroku!

```
$ git push staging 19-home-page-video:master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The only think I can see is in the code below, the three lines at the bottom that are `trying private keys` are keys that don't exist... Any suggestions?

```
$ ssh -v git@heroku.com
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.132] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version endosome
debug1: no match: endosome
debug1: Authenticating to heroku.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:8tF0wX2WquK45aGKs/Bh1dKmBXH08vxUe0VCJJWOA/o
debug1: Host 'heroku.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/micahsherman/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: According to your debug trace, the client offered the id_rsa key to the server, and the server didn't accept it. Assuming that key was supposed to work, there are half a dozen things on the server that could cause this. If you can, you should start by examining the server logs for an error message from sshd.

Comment: Thanks @Kenster, the fix was just to add the missing key...`$ heroku keys:add`.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Had to add key.  `$ heroku keys:add`